# How can I disable the seek bar for audio controller

Tags: android, seekbar, android-audiomanager

I'm currently using the following seekbar for showing my audio palying progress, i want to disable thumb movement by user.

```
<Seekbar
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:id="@+id/SeekBar01"
    android:layout_width="245dip"
    android:thumb="@drawable/seekthumb2"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:longClickable="false" />
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
android:enabled="false"
```

Comment: Audio.setEnabled("false"); //Working

Comment: **android:enabled="false"** is not working. **seekbar.setEnabled("false")** works (I'm on API Level 27)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `android:enabled="false"` as suggested by @yuku, but it will display disable effect [darken your seekbar].

So if you want to display enable seekbar with no response to thumb activity, implement touch event handler with return true as shown below.

```
seekBar.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a transparent png as a thumb. If none of the suggested solutions work.